# Is content hard-written in WP page templates indexable by search engines?

Tags: wordpress, seo

My client is concerned because he can't see the content of his pages in the WordPress dashboard. The reason is because the content of each page is hard-written in its own page template. I used templates for all pages because each one has a complicated layout with pieces of content scattered everywhere with different styles and everything.

My question is : is content hard-written in WP page templates equally indexable by search engines as norman page content (meaning written in the page's main text editor in the dashboard) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search engines see whatever your website spits out. They don't care what technology you use our whether it is hardcoded or dynamic. In fact they can't even tell because they don't see what's on your server.

So, no, there is no difference and it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for deleting your previous question. Appreciate not helping laziness.